# Linear algebra does the given line intersect plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Determine whether the line $x = (-1, 0, 1) + t(1, 2, 4)$ intersects the plane $2x-y+z=5$. Find the point of intersection if they intersect.

I know the equation follows the form $x = p + td$, so I know which is the point and which is the direction vector. From the general equation of the plane, I know the $n$ is $(2, -1, 1)$. After that, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Since you are trying to see if they intersect, try to see if any point that satisfies the equation of the line, also satisfies the equation of the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write the line in the form:
$$x=-1+t$$
$$y=2t$$
$$z=1+4t$$ and plug this in the equation of the given plane:
$$2(-1+t)-2t+1+4t=5$$
from here you will get $$t$$

Comment: Okay thanks! I found the point of intersection but how would I know that the line and plane intersect in the first place before trying to find a point of intersection unless I have to do what you did and solve for t and plug in the value to check?